# Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 33598:11: Bye Bye [preauth]

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sshd

Apparently my home server is getting checked out by a lot of bots online. I have daily more than 500 connection requests at port 11. Every attempt is performed only once a day for a specific IP address (as far as I can see), but they seem to retry every 3-6 days. Multiple attempts on a day are performed by distinct IP addresses. These attempts seem to get blocked so far, as I can't find any successful entries (besides my own) when `running sudo journalctl -u ssh`. Is this normal for a regular home server? My home server runs several websites on ubuntu 1804.

The connection requests are all blocked as far as I can see:

`Received disconnect from xx.xx.xx.xx port 33598:11: Bye Bye [preauth]`

I think I have hardened ssh to a reasonable level (public key with passphrase, no root login, fail2ban, mail notification on successful login, ...). Are there any measures I can/should deploy in order to prevent any problems?

Answer (score 1):

install a tool like fail2ban which adds the IP address to a deny list for a period of time. The frequency is low though, so maybe add the IP address to /etc/hosts.deny